# How to know UIWebView has finished loading

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

how can I check when user clicks and page has loaded? Delegate
`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`
Not working..

Comment: The `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate **does** work.  Perhaps you should show us the code where you are setting it up...

Answer (score 1):

When the user taps a link, the `UIWebView`'s delegate is sent the message `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and when the content is done loading, it sends the message `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

Make sure you've set the `delegate` property on the web view.

Comment: No Check it in your code, UIWebView Delegate don't working when I click link on a page.

Comment: I can absolutely guarantee you that it works if you've set the web view's delegate. The delegate must be a valid object, that implements the delegate methods you wish to respond to.

Comment: mazder, I'm doing exactly as I describe above, and it works like a charm. There's nothing to check. Post the the code where you set the web view's delegate, or describe your setup if you're doing it with IB. That'll make it easier to spot any errors in your code.

Comment: that's facebook url.. `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` working well but no didFinishLoad delegate.. the URL is "http://m.facebook.com/eventhome.php?refid=7" Try it please..